# Xamarin Forms - Customize FontFamily, FontSize of a DatePicker

Tags: datepicker, xamarin.forms, customization

I searched about how to change the fontsize/fontfamily of a `DatePicker` such as an `Entry`, but I couldn't find anything, any ideas?

Thank !

Answer (score 17):

You could do it via custom renderer:

For example, I will use renderer for **iOS**. `Control` will be native element for each platform. And you could change it in native way.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace SuperForms.Samples.iOS
{
    public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //Control is UITextField
            var someFontWithName = UIFont.FromName("fontName", 14);
            UIFont font = Control.Font.WithSize(14);
            Control.Font = font;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

For Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace SuperForms.Samples.Droid
{
    public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // Control is Android.Widget.EditText
            Control.Typeface = Android.Graphics.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "Path/To/YourFont.otf");

            Control.TextSize = 14;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me.  I just wanted to reduce the font size of the standard control so I removed the FontFromName line.

Comment: This approach working fine on iOs and Android. make this accepted answer

Comment: Is there a way to respect the users selection of the font size?

Comment: @Ernesto some global setting for font size and then redraw UI (not sure, but might work)

Answer (score 2):

```
**Xamarin Forms** => This is for **Android**, using **custom renderer** we can change the font size of datepicker.
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace  Samples.Droid
{
    public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
         protected override void        OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            **Control.TextSize = 12;**

         }
    }
}

Thank you
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if you require answer now, still i am attaching the code which solves the font size problem of date picker without using custom rendering..

Create `MainPage.Xaml` file

```
<DatePicker x:Name="PickerDate" MinimumDate="05-24-2017" Format="mm-dd-yyyy" MaximumDate="12-31-2050" IsVisible="False" DateSelected="PickerDate_DateSelected"/>
<Label x:Name="DateLabel" Text="Tap to Select Date" FontSize="14" HorizontalOptions="Start">
   <Label.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1"/>
   </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

create `MainPage.Xaml.cs` File

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PickerDate.Focus();
    }

    private void PickerDate_DateSelected(object sender, DateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DateLabel.Text = PickerDate.Date.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
    }
```

This solves problem in Android and IOS.